# Magento 2 getting interface implementation from admin config

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, di

I have an interface which gives me the country in which the customer is located.

```
interface CustomerLocatorInterface 
{
    public function getLocalCountryCode();
}
```

And I have two possible implementations:

```
class GetLocationByCookie implements CustomerLocatorInterface
{
    public function getLocalCountryCode()
    {
        //logic
    }
}

class GetLocationByDb implements CustomerLocatorInterface
{
    public function getLocalCountryCode()
    {
        //logic
    }
}
```

In my di.xml, I can assign either of these implementations to whichever constructor I require, however I want the implementation to be selectable in the admin config by the store owner.

How do I do this if the implementation is hard coded in the di.xml file? Is there any way you can pass a config value into the di.xml file?

Comment: I guees the [Magento Factories](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/factories.html) will do what you want. So you declare a factory parameter in the constructur. From that factory you get the actual CustomerLocataorInterace implementation (you have to implement a function that returns a CusomterLocator object). The factory would need to have some logic to make the decision, which might be reading a value that a admin user has set in the backend. Not sure... Does this make sense?